# Why does declaring objects voids the HTML in my Ajax page?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Background: I am building an Ajax page which will be called by a user's browser to retrieve data already loaded in $_SESSION. I want to test that the Ajax page works properly so I am trying to do a `print_r($_SESSION)` on it. (Note: the `print_r()` works fine on the main site.)

Problem: I cannot get my PHP to produce valid HTML. If I do:

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
  if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> <!-- See http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php-->
    <title>Test for Ajax</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="StyleSheetProjet" href="StyleSheetProjet.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <pre>
      Content of $_SESSION:
      <?php print_r($_SESSION) ?>
      </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

In which case the page shows:

```
Content of $_SESSION:
Array
(
```

followed by a bunch of `__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object` (because the objects in session have not been declared I assume).

However if I start with:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
//Obects in session:
require_once("Class_User.php");
require_once ('Class_Message.php');
if (!session_id()) {
  session_start();
}
//(Rest is same as above)
```

Then the browser renders nothing at all, not even `Content of $_SESSION:`. In fact, the html in the web console is simply `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` with nothing in between...

What am I doing wrong?

Edit 1: to replace `text/xml` in the `header()` with `text/html`.

Edit 2: I replaced the two `require_once` with:

```
if (file_exists('Class_User.php')) {
  echo "Class_User exists";
} else {
  echo "Class_User doesn't exist";
}

if (file_exists('Class_Message.php')) {
  echo "Class_Message exists";
} else {
  echo "Class_Message doesn't exist";
}
```

The page does return `Class_User existsClass_Message exists` so it clearly can find the files.

Comment: You're sending an XML header to an HTML & PHP  page, why?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have not started the sessions on the "local" page (where you run the AJAX from) that you will not have access to the session because a.) the local page was  not loaded after the session was started and 2.) you may need a reload. In addition you're outputting headers in your first example *before* you start the session and that will throw an error. You must start the session in any page using session variables *before* you do anything else.

Comment: Also - since you're dealing with Javascript, have you considered using a Javascript Native Object like JSON?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - The session is started on the main page. In fact I have a similar `print_r()` on the main site and it works fine.

Comment: @OliverQueen - I'm not sure what you are suggesting. The data is already in $_SESSION - why not use it? I will use JSON to send the $_SESSION data from the Ajax page to the main page (user side).

Comment: why are you sending `header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");` to the header? Anything that doesn't evaluate to valid XML with force an error.

Comment: It should (and will) throw an error if anything is malformed XML, not HTML.

Comment: @OliverQueen - That was a mistake on my part. Corrected & edited the question.

Comment: If your `require_once`s are not finding the files you are loading, the page will halt and wont show any output

Comment: Despite the change of content type, the fact you start with `echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';` means it's treated as xml.  But your content is not in an xml tag so it's not shown?  Try taking view source on the generated page

Comment: Is it not bad anymore to send output before `session_start()`?

Comment: I suspect error reporting is off. Turn it on and it becomes much easier. Then either check the logs or turn on `display_errors`.

Comment: @Adam Actually, this is an encouraged practice in XHTML documents. [check this w3 page](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/conformance.html)

Comment: Yes, for xml.  But if you're outputting stuff directly after the `<xml` and before you open any xml tags then it's not valid xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suspected Reason**

`require_once("Class_User.php");` and `require_once("Class_Message.php");` are looking for the related files, cannot find them, so stop executing the rest of the code. Check if the path to **Class_User.php** and **Class_Message.php** are correct.

**Actual Reason (we found working together w/ the OP after debugging)**

One of the class files was **extending another class** and since that file was not included in the project the execution was being blocked. The OP solved the issue by calling another `require()` for this third class.

Comment: And what is the server root? What does `echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];` print out in your page for AJAX?

Comment: So are your PHP files are under `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Project/Volumes/Docs/(.....)/Wamp/Project0.2` ?

Comment: Yes they all are in the same folder. (Interestingly I also have a complete set of files under `/Volumes/Docs/(.....)/Wamp/Project0.2` but those are not updated. I suspect they're a remnant of when I imported original files from a Windows machine.)

Comment: The thing is, if the two class files (Class_User.php and Class_Message.php) are not within the folder which is printed out by `echo __DIR__;` then you definitely have a relative path problem. In such a case, a quick solution is to define a complete path starting from the server root, something like `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/...../...../...../yourClassFile.php'`.

Comment: I understand but in this case they are.

Comment: And nothing changes when you replace require_once with include_once ?

Comment: Then one of the included files either have a die() or exit() command which gets executed for some reason or again one of the files cause the code execution to halt (probably because of another require or require_once within them).

Comment: This was the problem. One of my classes extends another class and I failed to require this one (the ancestor). Requiring the ancestor solves the problem. Noobie mistake. I'm going to mark your answer as correct to transfer the bounty to you. I suggest you edit your response to incorporate this last comment.